# Small lines showing after accesibility check of a PDF (created with pdfLatex)

Tags: pdftex, pdf, tex-core

After doing the accesibility check with Adobe Acrobat PDF, some small lines appear and some big parenthesis appear too. Why this happens? What can I do to avoid this lines appearing? Here it is the preamble.

```
\documentclass[11pt, leqno]{book} 
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} 
\usepackage{latexsym} 
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makeidx} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} %Fancy headers
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%   FORMAT
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-20pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{21.0cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{15.1cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-40pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{\thm@preskip=0pt
\thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother
\newtheoremstyle{newstyle}      
{10pt} %Aboveskip 
{} %Below skip
{\itshape} %Body font e.g.\mdseries,\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{} %Indent
{\bfseries} %Head font e.g.\bfseries,\scshape,\itshape
{.} %Punctuation afer theorem header
{ } %Space after theorem header
{} %Heading

\usepackage{enumitem, hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\namedlabel#1#2{\begingroup
    #2%
    \def\@currentlabel{#2}%
    \phantomsection\label{#1}\endgroup
}

\hypersetup{
    pdfinfo={
            Title={Title},
            Author={Author},
            Tipo={Tesis doctoral},
                }
}
```

[image: Capture]

This is result that we obtain when we:

1. Open with Adobe PDF the resulting PDF from my latex processor
2. Go to Tools
3. Go to Action Wizard
4. Do it accesible (I don't have the version in English)
5. Select Initiate

Comment: well adobe changed something so it is not really a LaTeX problem. But apart from this: you should put more effort in your question, simply dropping a preamble (or only a part of it?) and a screenshot and speaking vagely about an " accesibility check" is not enough. Nobody will be able to reproduce your problem with this.

Comment: you still don't show a small but complete document that can be used for a test.